# Is $a$ bigger than $0$ or not?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, real-numbers, paradoxes

Consider Goldbach's original conjecture (no need worry, because we don't talk about "Goldbach" itself):

> every integer $n> 2$ could be detached as a sum of three primes. (In Goldbach's age, $1$ is regarded as a prime.)

For any $n>2$, we denote the statement above as $p(n)$. Then define

$$a_n:=\begin{cases}
0, &\text{if $p(n)$ is true},\\
1, &\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$

Note that $a(n)$ is definite, since every $p(n)$ could be verified, at least by machine, as long $n$ is given. However, consider the decimal number $$a:=0.00a_3a_4a_5\cdots.$$

What's $a$? Is it a real number?

> If $a$ is a real number, then we can compare the magnitude of $a$ and
> $0$, since the real number field is **ordered**.

But we can't in fact. If $a=0$, then "Goldbach" is proven, and if not, then "Goldbach" is overturned. However, it's in suspense hitherto whether Goldbach is true or not.

Probably, we may say $a$ is **indefinite**, that's to say, we do not know what $a$ is yet. But a new question is coming about:

> Why we know any digit but do not know the number itself ? In order
> to know the number, what else we need ?

Further, let's compare $a$ with another classic number
$$\pi=3.1415926\cdots.$$

Indeed, we do not know all the digits of $\pi$ untill we compute every one. But we can safely say it's $\pi$. What's the exact difference between $a$ and $\pi$ on earth? Why we think we know $\pi$ but do not know $a$? In another word, what does "knowing a number" mean exactly? And in what sense can we say we know a number?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "we can know every digit of a"?

Comment: There is no paradox here. You correctly observe that we can have a very well-defined - even explicitly [computable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number) - real number $a$, yet be unable to prove whether or not $a=0$. Why should this be problematic, though?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg THX. Edited.

Comment: You can approximate $a$ well by computing the values of $a_i$'s over some bound but you cannot figure out what exactly the value of $a$ is until you prove the conjecture... Like you never know what value $a_i$ will show up for some very large $i$. I don't see why this problem makes any sense.

Comment: "Note that a(n) is definite, since every p(n) could be verified, at least by machine, *as long n is given*" .  there are infinitely many $n$.  We can only verify a finite many of them.  We can potentially know any $n$ we want but we will only know the ones that we actually *do* verify and potentially being able to verify any of them is not the same as actually verifying *everyone* of them.... Consider that you could read any page, but only one page of Moby Dick. Since each one of every page can be read does that mean you can read every page. No, it does not.

Comment: Just because we *can* verify any $a_k$ doesn't mean we *will* and we won't know what an $a_k$ is *until* we verify it.  And we are *NOT* going to verify all off them. we only have enough time in the history of the universe and the lifetime of every human being to verify maybe $10$ trillion of them.  And it's true we can verify *any* $10$ trillion but whichever ten trillion we *do* verify there will by infinitely more that we dont get around to verifying.

Comment: "we can know every digit of a"  No, we can not (atleast not yet we can't).  We can know *any* digit, but we can't know *every* digit.

Comment: Quite a genuine doubt...............

Comment: It may help to distinguish between (1) properties that are satisfied by exactly one real number, and (2) properties that a number might satisfy. Those of type (1) can be used to define a real number, and those of type (2) are questions we could ask about a number. As an example, one can prove by calculus methods (rates of increase and intermediate value theorem) that "$x^2 + 1 = 2^x$ and $4 < x < 5$" is satisfied by exactly one real number. Let's give this number a name, say $B.$ We can now ask things like is $B$ rational, what is the $10$th digit to the right of the decimal point of $B,$ etc.

Comment: I think you mean $n\ge6$.

Comment: @J.G. It doesn't matter. In Goldbach's age, $1$ is regarded as a prime yet.

Comment: @mengdie1982 $n\ge3$, then.

Comment: @J.G. YES. Edited.

Comment: Well, in a way we don't know $\pi$ much more than $a$.  We know $\pi$ is some value between $3.14159265$ and $3.14159266$ but not it's *exact* value.  And we know $a$ is very very close to $0$ and we *have* calculated it within it first few thousand decimal places. What we know of $\pi$ is everything that follows about the ratio of a circle to its diameter. That and nothing more. And we know that $a$ is a representation of the truth of Goldbachs conjector and everything that implies.  That and nothing more.

Comment: Here's a number for you.  Let $\pi_k$ be the $k$th digit of $\pi$.  Define $b_k=  \begin{cases} 0&\text{if }\pi_k < \pi_{\pi_k}\\5&\text{if }\pi_k = \pi_{\pi_k}\\9&\text{if }\pi_k>\pi_{\pi_k}\end{cases}$. Let $b=0.b_1b_2b_3.....$.  So or example $\pi_1=3$ and $p_3=4$ so $b_1=0$. $\pi_2=1$ and $\pi_1 = 3$ so $b_2=9$. And $pi_3=4$ and $\pi_4=1$ so $b_3=9$ and so $b = 0.099......$.  Do we know what $b$ is?  If we know what $\pi$ "is" we should.  But we *don't* know what $\pi$ is and we don't know what $b$ "is".

Comment: Consider $\pi+e=3.1415...+ 2.718...= 5.859..$. What do we know about $\pi+e$. Well, we know it "is" $\pi + e$. But is it irrational? Is it irrational algebraic? Is it transcendental?  We don't know.  but we can calculate any decimal but we only know what $\pi+e$ represents.  We don't "know" it completely.  Like wise your number $a$.  We "know' what it is.  We know what it represents but we don't 'know" is completely.  Just like we don't know the rationality of $\pi + e$ we don't know the zero equality of $a$.  To know what a number "is" is subjective and it doesn't mean knowing every decimal.

Answer (score 11):

What you have defined is a real number. Indeed, from the definition given it is also a [computable number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number). Does $a=0$? Well, this is something we simply do not know. Of course, there is nothing wrong with not knowing a number from a definition. For example, the [Ramsey number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem#Known_values) $R(6,6)$ is bounded between $102$ and $165$. However, we have no idea what this number is. Another example, define the number $x$ to be $0$ if the Riemann hypothesis is true and $1$ if it is false. This is a perfect definition, but I have no idea what $x$ is and if you can tell me you will get a million dollars.

**To reiterate:** One can write a perfectly sound mathematical definition and not know what that number actually is. This is not a paradox, but simply something that can arise naturally.

Comment: Why we know every digit and do not know the number itself? In order to know the number, what else we need ?

Comment: Do you know every digit of $\pi$? No? But defining $\pi$ as the ratio of the circumference to the diameter is a perfectly reasonable definition. We can find as many finite digits as we like but we can never know an infinite number of digits unless something else is proved. Same with your number $a$.

Comment: I say your Riemann number is 0, and my spouse says it's 1. Please send 1 million dollars to our joint account. ;-)

Answer (score 8):

You are confusing "we can verify *any* number of them" with "we can verify *every* one of them".  yes, we can verify any of the ones we choose to but we can't verify any of the ones we *don't* choose to, and as there are infinitely many of them there will always be an infinitely number of them we don't choose.

So although we can know *any* $a_i$, we can't know *every* $a_i$.

Imagine I asked you.  Can you read all of Moby Dick in 5 minutes.  You say no.  I ask how much of Moby Dick *can* you  read in 5 minutes.  You say one page, I guess.  And I ask which page can you read.  And you say well, any page.  And I say which pages *can't* you read.  And you answer well I could read *any* page.  so I say if you can read every page and there aren't any page you can't read then you *CAN* read all of Moby Dick in 5 minutes.

Is that a paradox?

Comment: Sir, please compare $a$ with $\sqrt{2}$. What's the difference between them, on the point " know" ? Why we know $\sqrt{2}$ but do not know $a$?

Comment: @mengdie1982: One can prove with significant machinery (Intermediate Value Theorem) that there is a unique positive real number whose square is $=2$. That number is usually called $\sqrt 2$, and we can in principle compute any digit of it. Everything "extra" we know about it is that by definition, it is a number whose square is $2$. Often when dealing with it, it is actually only that information that one uses (and e.g. its negative in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ can play the same role, or one of the two numbers in the $3$-adics $\mathbb Q_3$ whose square is $2$ ...).

Comment: [continued] Exercise: Define a real number $x$ where deciding whether the real number $\sqrt 2 \stackrel{?}= x$ or not is equivalent to some open conjecture.

Comment: We *don't* know all the digits of $\sqrt{2}$.  Why did you think we did?  We have methods to calculate them to whatever accuracy we want but we certainly don't know what they all are.

Comment: Maybe more strikingly, mengdie1982, how well do you think we "know" $\sqrt 2$? Do you know if the digit $7$ occurs infinitely often in its decimal expansion? I don't, and I think it is not known. (Cf. the same question about $\pi$: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2791/96384. If that is known about $\sqrt 2$, it would probably by some intricate argument via continued fractions. What really is not known, according to Wikipedia, is whether $0, ..., 9$ all have the same asymptotic density in $\sqrt 2$'s decimal expansion: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number)

Answer (score 7):

$a$ is a real number, defined by the definition you have given above.

It is [computable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number), in the sense that we can calculate it to arbitrary numerical precision via an algorithm.

However, it is not currently known whether $a=0$.

None of these statements are in conflict. In fact, there are many such cases in mathematics where there is some perfectly well-defined answer to a certain question, and where we could get successively better computational bounds that decide more and more of the digits of the number, but where we don't yet know whether those bounds will converge to a certain conjectural value.

The word "know" is doing a lot of work in this supposed paradox, and if you specify any particular notion of what it means to "know" what a number is you'll find that it is no longer an apparent contradiction.

Comment: Sir, my question is the last sentence.

Comment: Why we know every digit and do not know the number itself? In order to know the number, what else we need ?

Comment: We don't know every digit! Every digit is *knowable*, in the sense that a computer program could in theory compute it. But we do not actually know, say, the $n$th digit where $n=\lfloor e^{e^{e^{1000}}}\rfloor$.

Answer (score 1):

We can know **any** digit of $a$ (after a possibly very long but finite computation), but we do not currently know **every** digit. There is a difference: if you wanted to know the $n$th digit of $a$, give me some long but finite time, and I can tell you. But that is not the same as saying that I can tell you, currently, off the back of my mind, every single digit of $a$, for arbitrary $n$.

There is no paradox, you just need to be precise about the meaning of "know". You could say, for instance, that we *can know* any digit of $a$, but do not currently know every digit.