$p$-adic valuation of a binomial coefficient
Let $p\geq 3$ be an odd prime number. Let $1\leq m\leq n$ be two integers. My goal is to prove that
$$\binom{p^n}{m}\equiv 0\mod p^{n-m}.$$
In other words, I'd like to show that $p^{n-m}$ divides $\binom{p^n}{m}$. For this, I checked computationally what the $p$-adic valuation of $\binom{p^n}{m}$ is. It appears that we have the following stronger statement:

Conjecture. The $p$-adic valuation of $\binom{p^n}{m}$ is $n-1$ if $p$ divides $m$, and it is $n$ otherwise.

How can we prove this conjecture?

To tackle this problem, we can write
$$\binom{p^n}{m}=\frac{\left(p^n\right)^{\underline m}}{m!},$$
where for two positive integers $a$ and $b$, we write $a^{\underline b}:= a(a-1)\cdots(a-b+1)$, a falling factorial.
Now, it suffices to compare the $p$-adic valuation of $\left(p^n\right)^{\underline m}$ to the $p$-adic valuation of $m!$. To compute the latter, we may want to use:

Legendre's formula. For every prime number $p$ and every integer $m\geq 1$, it holds that
$$\nu_p(m!)=\sum_{k\geq 1}\left\lfloor\frac{m}{p^k}\right\rfloor.$$

Unfortunately, since Legendre's formula is not given in a closed form, I have trouble applying it in this scenario. In particular, using bounds such as $\nu_p(m!)\leq\frac{m}{p-1}$, following from Legendre's formula by not applying the floor function, seems not to work (at least not for the precise statement of the conjecture).

Are you sure about your Conjecture? Shouldn't the $p$-adic valuation be $n-k$ where $k$ is the $p$-adic valuation of $m$? That seems to be what @Qiaochu Yuan 's solution to this question suggests: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2791/binomial-coefficients-how-to-prove-an-inequality-on-the-p-adic-valuation?rq=1

For an integer $x$ and prime $p$, $x!$ has a factor of $p$ for each positive multiple of $p$ less than $x$ - that is $\lfloor \frac xp\rfloor$ factors of $p$.  In addition each positive multiple of $p^2$ less than $x$ provides another factor of $p$ giving us another $\lfloor \frac x{p^2}\rfloor$ factors of $p$.  Thus in total $$\nu_p(x!)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \left\lfloor \frac x{p^i}\right\rfloor$$
Thus $$\nu_p{p^n \choose m}=\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\left\lfloor \frac {p^n}{p^i}\right\rfloor- 
\left\lfloor \frac m{p^i}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor \frac {p^n-m}{p^i}\right\rfloor\right)$$
Clearly $$\left\lfloor \frac {p^n}{p^i}\right\rfloor- 
\left\lfloor \frac m{p^i}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor \frac {p^n-m}{p^i}\right\rfloor=
\begin{cases} 
0 &\text{if} \quad p^i\vert m\\1& \text{if}\quad p^i \not\vert m
\end{cases}
$$
Thus $$\nu_p{p^n \choose m}=n-\nu_p(m).$$
So your conjecture was correct when $\nu_p(m)=0,1$, but the correct generalisation is as above.
Regarding the original question:
$$m\geq p^{\nu_p(m)}>2^{\nu_p(m)}>v_p(m),$$
so $\nu_p{p^n \choose m}=n-\nu_p(m)>n-m$ and $p^{n-m}\vert {p^n \choose m}$.

As ${{p^n}\choose{m}}=\frac{p^n(p^n-1)\cdots(p^n-(m-1))}{m!}$, we pair the term $p^n-i$ on the top with $i$ on the bottom, for $i=1, \cdots, m-1$.
Note that $\nu_p(p^n-i)=\nu_p(i)$ for $i<p^n$ since $\nu_p(i)<n$.
Therefore all the $p$-adic valuations of the pairs cancelled each other, and only $p^n$ and $m$ are left, hence the result is just $$n-\nu_p(m)$$
So your stronger conjecture is false, but the original question can be answered now:
$$n-\nu_p(m)\ge n - m\Leftrightarrow m\ge \nu_p(m)$$
